# surfaceview take photo

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have a `SurfaceView`. Have to convert whatever it is onto the `SurfaceView` into `Bitmap`. I have searched for many sources. However, I must keep the `SurfaceView` for the QR code screening. That is to say, I cannot replace the `SurfaceView` by `TextureView`. I need to solve this in a hurry. Thanks. (I wont mind to use any existing library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For capturing image using custom camera use the below code you don't really need surface view

Camera Preview:

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private android.hardware.Camera mCamera;
Boolean isPreviewRunning = true;

public void startFaceDetection(){
    android.hardware.Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

    if (params.getMaxNumDetectedFaces() > 0){
        mCamera.startFaceDetection();
    }
}

public CameraPreview(Context context, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();

        startFaceDetection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("error", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
        return;
    }
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e){
        // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }



    if (isPreviewRunning)
    {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    }

    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();


    if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0)
    {
        parameters.setPreviewSize(height, width);
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    }

    if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90)
    {
        parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);
    }

    if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180)
    {
        parameters.setPreviewSize(height, width);
    }

    if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270)
    {
        parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
    }

    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        previewCamera();

    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("error", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}

public void previewCamera()
{
    try
    {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        startFaceDetection();
        isPreviewRunning = true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("preview", "Cannot start preview", e);
    }
}}
```

Camera Activity class:

```
public class FrontBackCamera extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private android.hardware.Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;
FrameLayout preview;
RelativeLayout effect_set;
ImageView button_capture,change_camera,imagePreview,video_camera,effect_none,effect_mono,effect_negative,effect_sepia,
        effect_posterize,effect_whiteboard,effect_blackboard,effect_aqua,flash_state_true,flash_state_false;
CardView button_gallery;
Boolean self_cam = true;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
String mCurrentPhotoPath;
CustomTextView current_zoom_level;
SeekBar camera_seek;
String[] effects = new String[]{
        "EFFECT_NONE",
        "EFFECT_MONO",
        "EFFECT_NEGATIVE",
        "EFFECT_SOLARIZE",
        "EFFECT_SEPIA",
        "EFFECT_POSTERIZE",
        "EFFECT_WHITEBOARD",
        "EFFECT_BLACKBOARD",
        "EFFECT_AQUA"
};

String[] scenes = new String[]{
        "SCENE_MODE_ACTION",
        "SCENE_MODE_AUTO",
        "SCENE_MODE_BARCODE",
        "SCENE_MODE_BEACH",
        "SCENE_MODE_CANDLELIGHT",
        "SCENE_MODE_FIREWORKS",
        "SCENE_MODE_HDR",
        "SCENE_MODE_LANDSCAPE",
        "SCENE_MODE_NIGHT",
        "SCENE_MODE_NIGHT_PORTRAIT",
        "SCENE_MODE_PARTY",
        "SCENE_MODE_PORTRAIT",
        "SCENE_MODE_SNOW",
        "SCENE_MODE_SPORTS",
        "SCENE_MODE_STEADYPHOTO",
        "SCENE_MODE_SUNSET",
        "SCENE_MODE_THEATRE"
};

HorizontalScrollView effects_slider;
Boolean effect_state = true;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_instance);

    setStatusbarTransperent();

    video_camera = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.video_camera);
    effects_slider = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.effects_slider);
    effect_none = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.effect_none);
    effect_mono = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.effect_mono);
    effect_negative = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.effect_negative);
    effect_sepia = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.effect_sepia);
    effect_posterize = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.effect_posterize);
    effect_whiteboard = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.effect_whiteboard);
    effect_blackboard = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.effect_blackboard);
    effect_aqua = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.effect_aqua);
    flash_state_true = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.flash_state_true);
    flash_state_false = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.flash_state_false);

    effect_set = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.effect_set);

    preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    button_capture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    button_gallery = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.button_gallery);
    change_camera = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.change_camera);
    camera_seek = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.camera_seek);
    current_zoom_level = (CustomTextView) findViewById(R.id.current_zoom_level);
    imagePreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagePreview);

    if (CommonUtil.getImagePath(FrontBackCamera.this) != null) {
        imagePreview.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(CommonUtil.getImagePath(FrontBackCamera.this)));
    }

    mCamera = getCameraInstance(0);
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    preview.addView(mPreview);

    video_camera.setOnClickListener(this);
    effect_set.setOnClickListener(this);
    flash_state_true.setOnClickListener(this);
    flash_state_false.setOnClickListener(this);
    effect_none.setOnClickListener(this);
    effect_mono.setOnClickListener(this);
    effect_negative.setOnClickListener(this);
    effect_sepia.setOnClickListener(this);
    effect_posterize.setOnClickListener(this);
    effect_whiteboard.setOnClickListener(this);
    effect_blackboard.setOnClickListener(this);
    effect_aqua.setOnClickListener(this);
    button_gallery.setOnClickListener(this);
    change_camera.setOnClickListener(this);
    button_capture.setOnClickListener(this);

    mCamera.setFaceDetectionListener(new MyFaceDetectionListener());
    camera_seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                      boolean fromUser) {
            current_zoom_level.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            zoom(progress + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    });


    if (CommonUtil.getFlashState(FrontBackCamera.this)){
        flash_state_true.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        flash_state_false.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else {
        flash_state_true.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        flash_state_false.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


}

public void setFlashOnOff(Boolean state){
    Log.d("method_cam",String.valueOf(state));
    if (state){
        Camera.Parameters param = mCamera.getParameters();
        param.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
        mCamera.setParameters(param);
        flash_state_true.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        flash_state_false.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else {
        Camera.Parameters param = mCamera.getParameters();
        param.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        mCamera.setParameters(param);
        flash_state_true.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        flash_state_false.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

public void setColorEffect(String effect){
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    switch (effect) {
        case "EFFECT_NONE":
            parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NONE);
            break;
        case "EFFECT_MONO":
            parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_MONO);
            break;
        case "EFFECT_NEGATIVE":
            parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NEGATIVE);
            break;
        case "EFFECT_SEPIA":
            parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_SEPIA);
            break;
        case "EFFECT_POSTERIZE":
            parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_POSTERIZE);
            break;
        case "EFFECT_WHITEBOARD":
            parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_WHITEBOARD);
            break;
        case "EFFECT_BLACKBOARD":
            parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_BLACKBOARD);
            break;
        case "EFFECT_AQUA":
            parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_AQUA);
            break;
    }
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
}


public void zoom(int zoomValue)
{
    Camera.Parameters params=mCamera.getParameters();
    params.setZoom(zoomValue);
    mCamera.setParameters(params);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public void setStatusbarTransperent(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
}


public static android.hardware.Camera getCameraInstance(int camera_id){
    android.hardware.Camera c = null;
    try {
        // change the value for selfie -> 1
        c = android.hardware.Camera.open(camera_id);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c;
}

private android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, android.hardware.Camera camera) {

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM),"Camera");
        try {
            File pictureFile = File.createTempFile(
                    imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                    ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                    storageDir      /* directory */
            );

            ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
            exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();

            mCurrentPhotoPath = pictureFile.getAbsolutePath();

            CommonUtil.setImagePath(mCurrentPhotoPath,FrontBackCamera.this);

            imagePreview.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath));

            preview.removeAllViews();
            preview.addView(mPreview);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("File", "not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("error", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.button_gallery:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://media/internal/images/media"));
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.button_capture:
            try {

               new MediaActionSound().play(MediaActionSound.SHUTTER_CLICK);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
            CommonUtil.setImagePath(mCurrentPhotoPath,FrontBackCamera.this);
            break;
        case R.id.change_camera:
            mCamera.release();
            decideCameraFacing();
            break;
        case R.id.video_camera:
            mCamera.release();
            startActivity(new Intent(FrontBackCamera.this,RearVideoCamera.class));
            break;
        case R.id.effect_none:
            setColorEffect(effects[0]);
            break;
        case R.id.effect_mono:
            setColorEffect(effects[1]);
            break;
        case R.id.effect_negative:
            setColorEffect(effects[2]);
            break;
        case R.id.effect_sepia:
            setColorEffect(effects[4]);
            break;
        case R.id.effect_posterize:
            setColorEffect(effects[5]);
            break;
        case R.id.effect_whiteboard:
            setColorEffect(effects[6]);
            break;
        case R.id.effect_blackboard:
            setColorEffect(effects[7]);
            break;
        case R.id.effect_aqua:
            setColorEffect(effects[8]);
            break;
        case R.id.flash_state_true:
            CommonUtil.setFlashState(false,FrontBackCamera.this);
            setFlashOnOff(false);
            break;
        case R.id.flash_state_false:
            CommonUtil.setFlashState(true,FrontBackCamera.this);
            setFlashOnOff(true);
            break;
        case R.id.effect_set:
            if (effect_state){
                effects_slider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                effect_state = false;
            }else {
                effects_slider.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                effect_state = true;
            }
            break;
    }
}


public void decideCameraFacing(){
    if (self_cam){
        self_cam = false;
        preview.removeAllViews();
        mCamera = getCameraInstance(1);
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        preview.addView(mPreview);
        change_camera.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.camera_rear));


    }else {
        preview.removeAllViews();
        mCamera = getCameraInstance(0);
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        preview.addView(mPreview);
        change_camera.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.camera_front));
        self_cam = true;

    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    mCamera.release();
    this.finish();
}


class MyFaceDetectionListener implements Camera.FaceDetectionListener {

    @Override
    public void onFaceDetection(Camera.Face[] faces, Camera camera) {
        if (faces.length > 0){
            Log.d("FaceDetection", "face detected: "+ faces.length +
                    " Face 1 Location X: " + faces[0].rect.centerX() +
                    "Y: " + faces[0].rect.centerY() );
        }
    }
}}
```

Xml for activity class

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/action_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_80"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/transparent_background">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/button_gallery"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_40"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_40"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_40"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/margin_10">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_1"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/margin_10">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagePreview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_capture"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/camera_icon" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/change_camera"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_30"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_30"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_40"
        android:src="@drawable/camera_front" />

</RelativeLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_15"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/seek_expose"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_32"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_200"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.mycamera.view.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/current_zoom_level"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_32"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_20"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/zero"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_16"
            app:font="@string/avenir_book" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_32"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_180"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/camera_seek"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_180"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_25"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:max="5"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_track"
                android:rotation="270"
                android:splitTrack="false"
                android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_thumb" />

        </FrameLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_32"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_20"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/flash_state_true"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_32"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_30"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_1"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_12"
            android:src="@drawable/flash_on"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/flash_state_false"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_32"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_30"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_1"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_12"
            android:src="@drawable/flash_off" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/effect_set"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_32"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_35"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_12"
            android:background="@drawable/swipe_left_image_card_background">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="@dimen/margin_3"
                android:src="@drawable/effect_icon" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/video_camera"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_32"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_30"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_1"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_12"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_videocam" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/effects_slider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_50"
    android:layout_above="@+id/action_layout"
    android:background="@color/transparent_background"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_5"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/effect_none"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_40"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_3"
            android:src="@drawable/filter_none" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/effect_mono"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_40"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_3"
            android:src="@drawable/filter_1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/effect_negative"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_40"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_3"
            android:src="@drawable/filter_2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/effect_sepia"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_40"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_3"
            android:src="@drawable/filter_4" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/effect_posterize"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_40"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_3"
            android:src="@drawable/filter_5" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/effect_whiteboard"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_40"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_3"
            android:src="@drawable/filter_6" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/effect_blackboard"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_40"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_3"
            android:src="@drawable/filter_7" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/effect_aqua"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_40"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_3"
            android:src="@drawable/filter_8" />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

CommonUtil class

```
public class CommonUtil {

public static void setImagePath(String photoPath, Context context){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.remove("picturePath");
    editor.putString("picturePath",photoPath);
    editor.apply();
}

public static String getImagePath(Context context){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return sharedPreferences.getString("picturePath",null);
}

public static void setFlashState(Boolean flash_state,Context context){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("flash_state",flash_state);
    editor.apply();
    Log.d("util_flashstate",String.valueOf(flash_state));
}

public static boolean getFlashState(Context context){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean("flash_state",false);
}}
```

Comment: you have the captured image url now you can transfer the image path from one activity to another activity using intent if you need any help to use the above code let me know.. i will guide you...